# How to use a boolean variable on a filter when filtering ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, boolean

I have difficulty trying to filter an ng-repeat list using a boolean from a select option

I've tried just placing the boolean from select with the {{}} and without the brackets.

```html
<div>  
    <select ng-model="mybool" ng-options="o.v as o.n for o in 
        [{ n: 'Not included', v: false }, { n: 'Included', v: true }]">
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the html in the table

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in model.items | filter:{enabled:mybool}">
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in model.items | filter:{enabled:{{mybool}}">
```

this is in the javascript file

```
$scope.mybool = true;
```

The list no longer displays when using the mybool variable. It only shows If I use the datatype true or false. I expect to see only the options where enabled is set to true or set false depending on what the option selected is.

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in model.items | filter:{enabled:true}">
<tr ng-repeat="item in model.items | filter:{enabled:false}">
```

these work but obviously they aren't dynamic since they are not linked to the select option.

I am new to angular and come from a java background so this is confusing me

Comment: have you tried using disabled inplace of enabled ?

Comment: sorry for late reply but enabled was a variable in the array not sure of inplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of double braces into ng-repeat expression. The first one is the right one:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in model.items | filter:{enabled:mybool}">
```

Just make sure that $scope.model is not undefined and $scope.model.items have the proper values.

The rest code seems ok and should work check this working example: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/h4pk2nsz/12/)

Comment: Thank you, you are right I just realised that the issue was something else but this was very helpful